# with open (name,"rb") as f need not close am i right?

Tags: python

I notice that I can open a file like this:

```
f=open("a.dat","rb")
```

And another method:

```
with open("a.dat","rb") as f:
```

In my opinion, if I use the first one, I must call f.close() function, while the second method need not. Am I right? Or there would be better method? Which one is the best to open a file in python? Thanks;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do not need to close the file as it is handled by `with` block.  If an exception occurs before the end of the block, it will close the file before the exception is caught by an outer exception handler.

Since python 2.5 (when `with` statement was introduced) using `with` statement with file operations is a preferable way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ankit because using with you no need to remember freeing of valuable resources even in the case of exceptions. For further information you can look at this [documentation](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Cheers!

Comment: This would have made a great comment to Ankit's answer; it's kind of redundant as an answer on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the document~That's so great!